# Math Behind a Loading Bar That Fills As Value for Percentage Decreases(Any Language)

Tags: math

IO've realized the question was poorly written and decided to rewrite it:

I'm making a bar is supposed to be synced to a timer so that as it gets closer to 0, the bar will fill more until when it hits 0, the bar is at 100%

So instead of filling more as the value for the percentage grows,  I'm wanting the value to be smaller and the bar fill more.

Comment: `current_value / max_value * 100`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That doesn't work if the values are not coming out to clean numbers (not sure how else to say it) The numbers im working with would be `TimeLeft / TotalTime * 100` and it doesnt work

Comment: `(current - min) / (max - min) * 100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math is fairly simple. For example say you want to represent the progress bar at 75% or just 75. We will represent percentage as a number from 0 to 100. The math is:

(percentage / 100) * totalWidthOfProgressBar

So if we want 75% of the bar full and the width of the progress bar was 100 units wide then then the math would be:

(75 / 100) * 100 = 75 units

If the progress bar's width was 200 units then the math would be:

(75 / 100) * 200 = 150 units

And 150 would be 75% of 200

This is one way but I am sure there are more ways to calculate this. Some progressBar objects have functions that will automatically calculate this for you. Take a look at the documentation of the progress bar you are using. Good luck and happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but re-reading my question I've realized it was poorly said. Your code worked fine but its still doing the decreasing method and I know why. **This bar is supposed to be synced to a count down timer**, so as the timer gets closer to 0, the bar fills more. (A progress bar for a timer essentially) so is there a way to change the code to grow the bar as the current percentage grows smaller? (so 0 is 100%)

Comment: @FirstOrderKylo Can't you just do `100 - whatever_equation_you_have` to make it go backwards?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that solved it! Thank you for your help!